# .NET Web API issues with deserializing JSON to object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I overtook a project which was developed by a company for us, unfortunately we do not get much support and in the long term, we should accomplish maintainence by ourselves for it. The application consists of a simple Web client (HTTP, JavaScript, Knockout Framework) and a REST API Service (.NET 4.5, ASP.NET MVC I guess).

Currently I am only modifiying the client, so the Server should still work as expected.

On the clientside I modified the Knockout View Model a little bit (added some computables and optimized presentation of some values). The View Model consists of 'Issues' and 'Comments' (as an array on issues, its an Bug tracker in fact). If I create a new issue, description is added to a first comment, the whole Model is JSON.stringified and the send to the .NET API Service. I prooved with Firebug, that the JSON that gets posted looks like this:

```
{
   "Id":0,
   "Title":"THis is a title",
   "Comments":[
       {
          "Id":1,
          "Text":"this is the first comment"
       }
   ]
}
```

On the client side, I have a "IssueController":

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostIssues( Issue issue ) {
   //issue should already hold the deserialized content of the JSON here,
   //but it only contains 'Id' and 'Title' not the 'Comments' (empty List)
   ...
}
```

The issue domain model object also has an array for holding comments, but on this end its empty already. The .NET code doesn't have any part which explicitely parses the JSON, as far as I understood it, the MVC Framework does this implicitely by equal property names (Is that right?).

The deserialization already worked as expected, so the .NET Code should be fine, but I looks like that I have modified the JSON in a way, that this implicit mapping of comments does not work anymore. Unfortunately I dont have much experiences with the .NET MVC Framework (or is it just the .NET WebAPI Framework, cannot even tell you that).

**These are my questions:**

1. What kind of .NET REST API Framework is that? How can I distinguish?
2. How is this implicit JSON deserialization working, and what are its pitfalls, for example when portions of the JSON doesn't get deserialized as expected? Especially on the client side (as I said, I didn't modify the server code)
3. Any ideas about what I could have done to the JSON, that the server doesn't like it anymore? ;)

---

EDIT

Issue.cs looks like this (simplified for sure):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Bo;
using Projects.DomainObjects;

namespace Projects.Models {


public class Issue : DomainObject {

    public Issue() {

        this.Comments = new List<Comment>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    private string _Title;
    public string Title { get { return _Title; } set { _Title = value; NotifyChanged(); } }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Common;
using Projects.DomainObjects;

namespace Projects.Models {


public class Comment : DomainObject {

    public Comment() {

    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the data-classes, like PostIssues? (Everything with "Id","Text","Comments { "Id", "Text"}

Comment: Is Comments property defined in DomainObject class?

Comment: DomainObject is an abstract class, just defining some really basic behaviours for the Domain Model classes. Nothing interesting in there I think, except you tell me what I should look for.

Comment: You didn't define a Comments property of field.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Sorry, you are right, was a typo due to translating german code to english ;) corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, the Problem was a computed that returns a sorted array of the comments. So my knockout model contains an

```
self.Comments = ko.observableArray([]); //...which gets filled with the comments of an issue
```

and a

```
self.CommentsSorted = ko.computed(function() {...}); //...which simply returns a sorted Comments array
```

So when I serialize this model, the posted JSON now represents the `Comments` Array, but also the `CommentsSorted` Array. Only when I do

```
var i = ko.toJS(issue);
delete i.CommentsSorted;
```

before I post `i` as data, .NET is able to deserialize `Comments` correctly.

The mysterious thing about this is, that there were always other computed fields in my knockout model, which get ignored completely by .NET and do not disturb deserialization in any way. So it seems that it depends mainly on the name and type of the fields in the model (perhaps if the first letters are equal?).

The good thing: it works now
The bad thing: it isn't really deterministic how .NET does the deserialization of JSON data and I am also not able to debug if it doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to your code straight from your post and it worked for me.

So there are a few things that may be going wrong on your side:

- When you post the object to the server, make sure you are converting back from Knockout observable to a json object. So in your ajax request, make sure it looks like: `data: ko.toJSON(issue)` and not just `data: issue`.
- When you post the object to the server make sure you sent header `content-type: application/json`

Here are the answers to your other questions:

*What kind of .NET REST API Framework is that? How can I distinguish?*

This doesn't look like anything custom (at least, what you posted) it is just straight Web API in .NET.

*How is this implicit JSON deserialization working, and what are its pitfalls, for example when portions of the JSON doesn't get deserialized as expected? Especially on the client side (as I said, I didn't modify the server code)*

Deserialization on the server uses the collection of formatters that work based on the `content-type` set by the client. This can get complex if you want to customize it but there is information [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding)

*Any ideas about what I could have done to the JSON, that the server doesn't like it anymore? ;)*

As I said your code worked for me!

Comment: Mhm, very strange, as I said, the original code is not mine, and so its also hard to get my head around some things. Originally before the observable was posted, there was a `var i = JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(issue));` (I guess to some kind of validate the resulting JSON). Then the original programmer did a `data: ko.toJS(i)` to pass the data to ajax post function. In Firebug I also checked that content-type is application/json. Then I used `ko.toJSON(issue)` as you suggested, the resulting post was the same, but on the server side the issue object is still deserialized without the comments.

Comment: Could there be a problem, because all of the computed fields of the observable (I have an "SortedComments", "FirstComment", "LastComment") are also contained in the JSON, but do not have an equivalent Field on the server side? Does the mapping fail, if too much fields cannot be mapped correctly?

Comment: No it should just ignore them. I suggest put a breakpoint at the first line of PostIssues() and check the posted object. Since your code worked for me it must be something is happening on the server after the object is mapped. I know you said you didnt change the server but we can see the data being sent correctly so with firebug so I dont know how else to troubleshoot.

Comment: At the first Line I only have the Deserialized Issue Object (as it is a parameter of PostIssue) and the "Request" object itself which has its content in an DataStream Object. So I have to write a StreamReader first to pull the raw JSON out of there. I'll need some time for this, but I'll let you know what I was able to inspect.

Comment: Problem solved: Never thought that it could be that...provided my own answer for it. If you can tell my why .NET is acting like this, I'll be thankful with plenty of +1es